# Uniform sub-linearity of sub-additive functions on groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory, random-walks

Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated group and suppose $f: G \to \mathbb{R}$ is subadditive function, that is: $f(g_1\circ g_2) \leq f(g_1) + f(g_2)$. One example of such $f$ is the word length in some generating set.

Suppose the following is true for our $f$:

Given any probability measure $\mu$ on $G$, we have that the random walk on $G$ defined by $\mu$ satisfies that for $\mu^{\mathbb{N}}$almost every word $w \in G^{\mathbb{N}}$ the following limit holds:

$$ \lim \frac{f(w_n)}{n} = 0 $$

Where $w = (x_0,x_1,....)$ and $w_n = x_n\circ w_{n-1}$.

I'm wondering whether this statement implies that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exist $n_\epsilon$ such that: $$f(w) \leq n\epsilon$$ for EVERY word $w$ of length $n \geq n_{\epsilon}$ in some fixed generating set $S$ of $G$.

For example, for $G= \mathbb{Z}$, it is easy to see it's true by taking $\mu$ the dirac probability measure supported in the generator of $\mathbb{Z}$. The same is true if $G$ is abelian or nilpotent.

1) Is this true for any f.g. group $G$?

2) What if $G$ is amenable?, or the Grigorchuk group?, are there any other nice family of groups for which this is true?

3) What if one adds the weaker assumption that $\mu$ has to be compactly supported?

Anything that seems vaguely related or relevant to these questions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $G=\mathbb Z$ and $f(n)=|n|$, then $f$ is subadditive. Let $\mu$ be the Dirac measure giving mass $\frac 12$ to $+1$ and $\frac 12$ to $-1$. Then you have (by the strong law of large numbers) that $f(w_n)/n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ for almost every $\mathbf w$. But it's *not* true that there's an $\epsilon$ such that $f(w)\le n\epsilon$ for every word of length $n\ge n_0$.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: this is no contradiction. The question is whether $(\forall \mu, P(\mu,f))\Rightarrow Q(f)$, where $P(\mu,f)$ is the limit property of the random walk and $Q(f)$ means that $f$ is subadditive. You give an example for which for *some* $\mu$, $P(\mu,f)$ holds and $Q(f)$ does not hold, this is no contradiction. The trivial proof given for $\mathbf{Z}$ works.